# Python 3 Print Update on multiple lines

Tags: python

Is it possible to print and update more than one line?
This works for one line:

```
print ("Orders: " + str(OrderCount) + " Operations: " + str(OperationCount), end="\r")
```

and get this: (Of course the numbers update because its in a loop)

```
Orders: 25 Operations: 300
```

I have tried this:

```
print ("Orders: " + str(OrderCount) + "\rOperations: " + str(OperationCount), end="\r\r")
```

and get this: (The number does update correctly)

```
Operations: 300
```

Looking for two lines that are updated like:

```
Orders: 25
Operations: 300
```

and not:

```
Orders: 23
Operations: 298

Orders: 24
Operations: 299

Orders: 25
Operations: 300
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`\r` is a *carriage return*, where the cursor moves to the start of the line (column 0). From there, writing more text will overwrite what was written before, so you end up only with the last line (which is long enough to overwrite everything you've written before).

You want `\n`, a newline, which moves to the next line (and starts at column 0 again):

```
print("Orders: " + str(OrderCount) + "\nOperations: " + str(OperationCount), end="\n\n")
```

Rather than use `str()` and `+` concatenation, consider using string templating with [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print("Orders: {}\nOperations: {}\n".format(OrderCount, OperationCount))
```

or a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
print(f"Orders: {OrderCount}\nOperations: {OperationCount}\n")
```

If you wanted to use `\r` carriage returns to update two lines, you could use [ANSI control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences); printing `\x1B[2A` (*ESC [ 2 A*) moves the cursor up 2 times, adjust the number as needed. Whether or not this works depends on [what platform you are supporting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Platform_support).

On my Mac, the following demo works and updates the two lines with random numbers; I used the ESC [ 0 K to make sure any remaining characters on the line are erased:

```py
import random, time

orders = 0
operations = 0

UP = "\x1B[3A"
CLR = "\x1B[0K"
print("\n\n")  # set up blank lines so cursor moves work
while True:
   orders += random.randrange(1, 3)
   operations += random.randrange(2, 10)

   print(f"{UP}Orders: {orders}{CLR}\nOperations: {operations}{CLR}\n")

   time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 2))
```

Demo:

[image: Animated GIF demonstrating 2 lines updating several times]

You could also switch to a full-terminal control with [Curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) or stick to putting everything on one line. If you are going to go the Curses route, take into account that Windows compatibility is sketchy at best.

Comment: Both these solutions don't update the console:
I get:
Orders: 88
Operations: 197
Orders: 88
Operations: 198

Of course lots more lines than that

Comment: @MatthewCox: looking at your comment source, I see newlines. You are not being clear then; pleas update your question to explain what output you *expected*.

Comment: Ok, thanks!!
Dang! your fast!!
(You gotta give me more than 30 seconds to update my own edits!!)  :)

Comment: What if I want to add a third line and then update its values with others. How should I change the code to get it working.

Comment: @ParasGupta: Try to think this through; if you had to use your cursor keys to do this manually, you'd need to go up 4 times, not three. So adjust the `UP` ANSI code to replace `3` with `4`. Or, as my answer states: *adjust the number as needed*.

Comment: I tried yours but i see still new lines  from my terminal, you may need to change to this
`print(f"{UP}Orders: {orders}{CLR}Operations: {operations}{CLR}", end="\r")`

Comment: @DagicCross: that's the point, the demonstration prints multiple lines and keeps those multiple lines updated. Removing the `\n` newlines and using `\r` (carriage return) *defeats the whole purpose*.

Answer (score 1):

This is more an 'upgrade' than an 'answer'. Using 'Martijn Pieters' answer I make an function that do the carriage return not just for 2 lines only but for any you want and whenever you want (example 1). You can also do a normal print and this print will keep in screen, useful for display errors or debugs (example 2). I using Windows 11 with PowerShell terminal.

```py
    last_nrows = None # Global variable
    def print_csi( msgs:list ):
        global last_nrows
        
        csi_up = f"\x1B[{last_nrows}A"
        csi_clr= "\x1B[0K"
        
        if last_nrows is None: # only executed one time when last_nrows is resetted (None)
            print('\n'*(len(msgs)-1))
            csi_up = f"\x1B[{len(msgs)}A"
        else: # clear the prompt if new msgs have less rows than the previous msgs, else overwrite
            if last_nrows > len(msgs):
                print(f'{csi_up}{csi_clr}')
                for r in range( 1, last_nrows ): print(f'{csi_clr}')
        
        last_nrows = len(msgs)
        print(f'{csi_up}{msgs[0]}{csi_clr}')
        for r in range( 1, len(msgs) ): print(f'{msgs[r]}{csi_clr}')

    print_csi( ['Line 1', 'Line 2'] ) # Call function - 'msgs' can not be empty
```

Exemple 1 - Code:
I take random number of rows to print and I clear it at the end.

```py
    for i in range(10):
        # Create random list from 1 to 9 rows
        msgs = list()
        msg_nrows = random.randrange(1, 10)
        for rows in range(msg_nrows):
            msgs.append( f'NRows: {msg_nrows} - ' + f'{rows+1}'*9 ) 
        print_csi(msgs)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    time.sleep(2)
    print_csi(['']) # Clear rows
```

Example 1 - Demo:
[image: Animated GIF demonstrating the first example]

Example 2 - Code:
Same as example 1 but I do a normal print in the middle and it keeps in screen - to do this you need to reset 'last_nrows' to None. Only problem is  an empty line is create everytime you reset 'last_nrows'.

```py
    for j in range(5):
        last_nrows = None # Need to be resetted
        print('DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE')
        for i in range(2):
            # Create random list from 1 to 9 rows
            msgs = list()
            msg_nrows = random.randrange(1, 10)
            for rows in range(msg_nrows):
                msgs.append( f'NRows: {msg_nrows} - ' + f'{rows+1}'*9 ) 
            print_csi(msgs)
            time.sleep(0.7)
        print_csi(['']) # Clear rows
```

Example 2 - Demo:
[image: Animated GIF demonstrating the second example]

Answer (score -2):

You probably want `\n` instead of `\r`. `\r` is "carriage return", a.k.a. "go back to the beginning of the line" -- so you're print "Operations" over "Orders".