# Update only two lines in print inside jupyter notebbok

Tags: python, printing, jupyter-notebook, stdout

I want to print only two lines in my cycles, I started with the following:

```
import time

for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    for j in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('Index1:', i)
        print('Index2:', j)
```

I tried different combinations of `\r`, `\n`, `flush=True` etc. at the beginning and end of `print`, but wasn't successful((

What I'd like to see is as in the GIF of accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455022/python-3-print-update-on-multiple-lines)

I tried those code, but it didn't help, maybe because my OS is Windows or I use `jupyter notebook`, I have no idea((

Comment: Could you show a sample of what you expect please ?

Comment: Plus an example of the wrong output you currently see.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to print two separate lines but then write back over them? From my experiences with \r I couldn't get anything to work, but try printing both `i` and `j` in the same print function but separated by \n

Comment: @KingTasaz, `\n` in one print doesn't help, each cycle it outputs two new lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jupyter Notebook, you can clear current cell output using `IPython.display.clear_output(wait=True)`

In terminal, similiar behaviour can be achieved using ANSI escape codes, as in the following snippet:

```
import time

n = 15
for i in range(n):
    print(f"{i}s passed")
    print(f"{n-i}s remaining")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\u001b[2A", end="") #ANSI escape code for cursor up 2 lines
```

Comment: no, your code also outputs each cycle two new lines

Comment: Then you need to be more clear about your actual vs expected output

Comment: this code works like you wanted it to when run in terminal. For Jupyther Notebook try `IPython.display.clear_output(wait=True)`

Comment: thank you! that's what I need! I just need to import IPython in my environment to make it alive

Comment: @matszwecja Please update your answer. Others that come here will see yours as the accepted answer and find that it does not have the desired effect. You can include your cursor up code, perhaps commented so that people know it is not for Jupyter.

Answer (score 2):

For Jupyter import `clear_output` from `IPython.display`. On terminal you can use something like `os.system('clear')` for Linux or `os.system('cls')` for Windows.

```
import time
import os
from IPython.display import clear_output

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        print(f'Index1: {i}\nIndex2: {j}')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        # for terminal ('clear' for Linux, 'cls' for Windows)
        # os.system('clear')
        # for Jupyter 
        clear_output(wait=True)
```

Comment: also doesn't work(( your code outputs each cycle two new lines

Comment: Where are you executing it? Try it on terminal.

Comment: I need to execute it in jupyter notebook

Comment: Try `clear_output(wait=True)` instead of `os.system('cls')`.

Comment: from which library this method? I don't have it neither in the standard environment nor in time package

Comment: `from IPython.display import clear_output`

Comment: @Curious pshh I was the first to suggest this yet don't get the accepted answer! :P jokes Hope your problem is solved! Happy coding!

Comment: If I could accept both answers(( thank you so much for very helpful answers, I really appreciate it!)

Comment: @oda have an upvote instead :P

Answer (score 0):

remember that you must use `end` inside `print()`

**try this code:**

```py
import time

for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    for j in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(f'\rIndex1: {i}, Index2: {j}', flush=True, end='')
```

Comment: sure, I tried it, but wasn't successful; your code is good, but only one line, I need two